# Using Structuremap how do i inject a property of an MVC Controller into the Constructor of a Service the Controller uses

Tags: asp.net, structuremap

I'm new to using StructureMap as an IOC container for asp.MVC. One of my controllers takes an IStreamService interface in the constructor.

This is easily linked to a concrete class implementation of StreamService like so

```
For<IStreamService>().HttpContextScoped().Use<StreamService>();
```

The problem i'm facing is that the concrete class constuctor takes an IPrincipal parameter, which needs to be injected. I want to pass the User property of the instantiating Controller into the Concrete Service. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you really need to pull the IPrincipal from the controller? It is much easier if you just pull it off of the HttpContext, as Robin suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Forget the fact that IPrincipal happens to be a property which is accessible from HttpContect. How could i do it if it was another property which i needed from the controller. ie Not accessible from HttpContext. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: How could this work?  Are saying that MyController has a dependency on StreamService, which in turn has a dependency on MyController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem, just add this line to your configuration:

```
For<IPrincipal>().Use(() => HttpContext.Current.User);
```

The use of a lambda causes this to be evaluated every time the dependency is requested (as opposed to being a single instance at configuration time.

Comment: Hi Robin. Thanks for your suggestion and that seems to be the way to go for properties accessible from HTTPContext or others which are accessible from singletons etc, but say the property was only accessible from an instance of the Controller. Ie Say it was a property i created, and it needed to pass in the property on instantiating the Service class, is that possible?

Comment: That sounds like a circular reference, if you need the service to instantiate the controller and you need the controller to instantiate the service...

Comment: The only thing I can think of (other than changing your design, which would be best) is to use property injection to inject the controller property into the service after they are both created. See the documentation: http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ConstructorAndSetterInjection.htm#section8